# extract-text-webpack-plugin error on production file

Tags: reactjs, webpack-2, production-environment, html-webpack-plugin

I have a problem with extract-text-webpack-plugin when I execute webpack to production. the error is this:

```
sh-3.2# yarn build
yarn build v0.24.5
$ webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js -p --watch --progress
 10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active
Webpack is watching the files…

 78% advanced chunk optimization/Users/bcgarcia/Documents/tutoriales/redux/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:188
            chunk.sortModules();
                  ^

TypeError: chunk.sortModules is not a function
    at /Users/bcgarcia/Documents/tutoriales/redux/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:188:19
    at /Users/bcgarcia/Documents/tutoriales/redux/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3083:16
    at eachOfArrayLike (/Users/bcgarcia/Documents/tutoriales/redux/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1003:9)
    at eachOf (/Users/bcgarcia/Documents/tutoriales/redux/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1051:5)
    at Object.eachLimit (/Users/bcgarcia/Documents/tutoriales/redux/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3145:5)
    at Compilation.<anonymous> (/Users/bcgarcia/Documents/tutoriales/redux/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:184:27)
    at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (/Users/bcgarcia/Documents/tutoriales/redux/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:142:13)
    at Compilation.seal (/Users/bcgarcia/Documents/tutoriales/redux/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:570:8)
    at /Users/bcgarcia/Documents/tutoriales/redux/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:474:16
    at /Users/bcgarcia/Documents/tutoriales/redux/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:225:11
    at _addModuleChain (/Users/bcgarcia/Documents/tutoriales/redux/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:472:11)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (/Users/bcgarcia/Documents/tutoriales/redux/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:443:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

here is my webpack.config file to production:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const extractTextWebpackPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
        modules: [
            path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
            'node_modules'
        ]
    },
    entry: [
        path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.jsx')
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {

        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: { loader: 'babel-loader'}
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'style-loader' },
                    { loader: 'css-loader' }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: 'file-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/,
                use: 'url-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000'
            },
            {
                test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': { NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV) || 'development' }
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(true),
        new extractTextWebpackPlugin(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'styles.css')),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: "redux tuto",
            template: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html'),
            filename: 'index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: { warning: false },
            mangle: { except: ['$super', 'exports', 'require'] }
        }),
    ],
    target: 'web',
    devServer: { 
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        hot: false,
        port: 8081,
        inline: true,
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, './build'),
        historyApiFallback: true,
    }
}
```

and the versions of packages are the next:
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
"style-loader": "^0.18.2",
"webpack": "2.2.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "2.4.0"

does anyone know which is the problem? I have updated node and the error persists.

thanks in advance.

Comment: probably because the versions of webpack and extract-text-webpack-plugin are not compatible. try removing your node_modules folder and downgrade extract-text: `yarn add extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.1.2`. then do a `yarn` and try again..

Comment: yeah, problem version i have installed this version (2.1.2) and ir runs ok